# MySQL Connector is not working while I'm trying to add data into the table

Tags: mysql, jsp, jdbc

I'm working on a sign up page and while inserting the values in the table it shows the error that no suitable driver found. I have added MySQL connector in it.

Here is the error message:
[image]

Here is the code for connecting to the database:

```
package Admin;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class ConnectionWithDb {
    
    private static final String USERNAME = "sweta";
    private static final String PASSWORD = "dhanuk";
    private static final String CONN = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:9999/inventory";
    
    public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException{
        return DriverManager.getConnection(CONN, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
    }
}
```

Here is the signup page:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>


<%@ page import="Admin.ConnectionWithDb" %>
<%@page import="java.sql.*,java.util.*"%>
<%
    String first_name=request.getParameter("fname");
    String last_name=request.getParameter("lname");
    String emailid=request.getParameter("email");
    String cont=request.getParameter("contact");
    String add=request.getParameter("address");
    String usname=request.getParameter("username");
    String pwd=request.getParameter("passw");
    
    Connection con = null;
    con = ConnectionWithDb.getConnection();
    PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO users (user_fname, user_lname, 
    user_emailid, user_address," + "user_contact, username, password)" + "VALUES 
    ('"+first_name+"','"+last_name+"','"+emailid+"','"+cont+"', '"+add+"','"+usname+"','"+pwd+"')");
    
     int i = pst.executeUpdate();
        if(i != 0){
            System.out.println("The data has been successfully inserted");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("There was an error inserting the data");
        }
%>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <jsp:include page="header1.jsp" />
   <body class="sign-in-up">
      <section>
      <div id="page-wrapper" class="sign-in-wrapper">
         <div class="graphs">
            <div class="sign-up">
                <form name="registration_form">
               <h3>Register Here</h3>
               <p class="creating">Please fill your required details in the form provided.</p>
               <h5>Personal Information</h5>
               <div class="sign-u">
                  <div class="sign-up1">
                     <h4>First Name* :</h4>
                  </div>
                  <div class="sign-up2">
                    
                        <input type="text" placeholder=" " required=" " name="fname"/>
                     
                  </div>
                  <div class="clearfix"> </div>
               </div>
               <div class="sign-u">
                  <div class="sign-up1">
                     <h4>Last Name* :</h4>
                  </div>
                  <div class="sign-up2">
                     
                      <input type="text" placeholder=" " required=" " name="lname"/>
                     
                  </div>
                  <div class="clearfix"> </div>
               </div>
               <div class="sign-u">
                  <div class="sign-up1">
                     <h4>Email Address* :</h4>
                  </div>
                  <div class="sign-up2">
                     
                      <input type="text" placeholder=" " required=" " name="email"/>
                     
                  </div>
                  <div class="clearfix"> </div>
               </div>
               <div class="sign-u">
                  <div class="sign-up1">
                     <h4>Contact Details :</h4>
                  </div>
                  <div class="sign-up2">
                     
                        <input type="text" placeholder=" " name="contact"/>
                     
                  </div>
                  <div class="clearfix"> </div>
               </div>
               <div class="sign-u">
                  <div class="sign-up1">
                     <h4>Address :</h4>
                  </div>
                  <div class="sign-up2">
                     
                      <input type="text" placeholder=" " name="address"/>
                     
                  </div>
                  <div class="clearfix"> </div>
               </div>
               <h6>Login Information</h6>
               <div class="sign-u">
                  <div class="sign-up1">
                     <h4>Username* :</h4>
                  </div>
                  <div class="sign-up2">
                     
                        <input type="text" placeholder=" " required=" " name="username"/>
                    
                  </div>
                  <div class="clearfix"> </div>
               </div>
               <div class="sign-u">
                  <div class="sign-up1">
                     <h4>Password* :</h4>
                  </div>
                  <div class="sign-up2">
                     
                      <input type="text" placeholder=" " required=" " name="passw"/>
                    
                  </div>
                  <div class="clearfix"> </div>
               </div>
               <!--<div class="sign-u">
                   
                  <div class="sign-up1">
                     <h4>Confirm Password* :</h4>
                  </div>
                  <div class="sign-up2">
                     
                        <input type="password" placeholder=" " required=" " name="conf_pass"/>
                     
                  </div>
                  <div class="clearfix"> </div>
               </div>-->
               <div class="sub_home">
                  <div class="sub_home_left">
                     
                      <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit_button">
                     
                  </div>
                  
                  <div class="clearfix"> </div>
               </div>
                </form>
                <div>
                    <p style="color:red">* marked fields are mandatory.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <jsp:include page="footer1.jsp" />
   </body>
</html>
```

I have also added the MySQL Connector, please tell me if I have added it in the right folder or not.

[image]